# How to burn a boot loader onto a USB drive (boot-loader as a .bin)

Tags: bootloader, binary-files, x86

I have created a very small boot loader in assembly and am wanting to test it on my physical hardware and so I am using a USB drive to do this. I have converted the assembly to machine code and to a .bin file, I ran the file command on my bin file and I got:

DOS/MBR boot sector

So I know that it is bootable, and I am also able to run it properly in an emulator.

I have been googling this issue for over 4 hours and I can't find anything that works, many people say to use Rufus, but I do not see any setting in Rufus 3.3 that will flash a bin file to a USB drive.

I have a Unix and Windows machine, so any method will do.

I have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to burn a .bin boot loader to a USB and boot from it, if anyone knows what to do, that would be great.

As a reference, here is the code:

```
BITS 16


start:
    mov ax, 07C0h
    add ax, 288
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096
    
    mov ax, 07C0h
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, helloText
    call printStr   


    jmp $

    helloText db "Hello, World!", 0


printStr:
    mov ah, 0Eh


.repeat:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done
    int 10h
    jmp .repeat
    
.done:
    ret
    


TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

I assembled the code with the following NASM commands:

```
nasm -f bin -o bootLoad.bin bootLoad.asm
```

From here I need to burn the bin to a USB drive and boot from it. Does anyone have any tools, or information on how to ACTUALLY do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (1) Writing to optical media (e.g. CD or DVD) is called *"burning"* because there is a chemical reaction.  Writing to NAND flash (or ferrite oxide) does not involve any chemical reaction, so *"burning"* a USB (flash) drive is incongruous. (2) Bootloaders are CPU or even board-architecture specific.  Your use of the `x86` is really not specific enough.  For an x86 PC (that executes the PC BIOS on startup), the *"bootloader"* is fetched from the MBR (which is at LBA `0`) of the designated boot drive/device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this really doesn't answer my question. I understand how the boot loader works and the fact about x86, what I am asking is HOW do I get my code to that specific location on my USB so the bios can read it and boot from it? I have been able to run it properly in emulators and things, but I want to test it on my physical hardware. If you know any tools, methods, or information for getting a boot-loader flashed onto a USB that would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under linux one would typically use dd to 'burn' images to a drive. Try:

sudo dd if=/path/to/bootloader.bin of=/path/to/drive bs=1M

'if' is short for input file and 'of' for output file and would typically point to /dev/sda. If you dont know what you drive is called type 'sudo fdisk -l' first.

Comment: This works to a sense, when I run this command it places the binary on the device but the USB is no longer FAT partitioned and I can't actually view it, I only know the binary is there because I can check and see that the USB isn't 100% empty. When I try to boot the USB, the BIOS can't read the USB or my binary for that matter, normally the BIOS doesn't have an issue but some reason does when I run that command.

Comment: I have goo news and I have bad news, the good one is that the code works on my notebook. I tried it out and it actually worked fine. The bad news is, it only worked on my about 13 year old notebook and not my modern one. I guess on newer systems the boot menu only shows drives with partitions. You might want to check if you have legacy support enabled in your BIOS settings. If it doesn't i don't know anything either. Here is a picture if you want to see it tough: https://ibb.co/bv2gt82

Answer (score 0):

@murderbaer has the correct answer.

> sudo dd if=/path/to/bootloader.bin of=/path/to/drive bs=1M

> if' is short for input file and 'of' for output file and would typically point to /dev/sda. If you dont know what you drive is called type 'sudo fdisk -l' first.

> The only problem is that modern computers / boot menus don't support drivers without partitions, the code will however work and is bootable if you have legacy support enabled in your BIOS.